# Google Maps v3 autocomplete trigger focus

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to embed google maps autocomplete in my script. As an example the api is asked to find "Neustadt" in Germany. There are a few possible matches to be shown. For that purpose this is fired:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(document.getElementById('search'), 'focus', {} );
```

The autocomplete text input expands and (hurray) the alternatives are shown.
BUT if you click on one nothing happens.
Expected behavior: Show the selected place.

Whats wrong? Any known cure?

Any hint appreciated a lot.

Comment: You need to take that selected location..... If you don't have lat lng geocodezip it....... Take the lat lng and create your map..... Setting center on your lat lng hth

Comment: The best awnser is the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no object in the Google Maps API V3 which has a **'`focus'`** event. With `google.maps.event.trigger()`, you can only trigger the [**documented events**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference). If you're trying to trigger an event in a DOM element you can do so directly, ie:

```
document.getElementById('search').focus();
```

Comment: I had it that way in the first place. That didnt work. But now I put a little delay before focus and that was it.